# Shoutcast player for aacPlus v2 without RTMP

Tags: flash, streaming, aac, shoutcast

I'm not getting a functional player for my shoutcast radio aacPlus v2.

I'm on my days looking for a solution, already tested the player's own shoutcast does not work. The player Daniel Brinca works perfectly but I can not buy because it is too expensive for me at the moment and do not think a way to customize it, I only advertise for other radios.

This is the ip address and port for my radio aacPlus, if anyone has any suggestions I am very grateful.

```
http://66.7.203.107:9318
```

Ps:. Put my ip and port on the winamp player and works perfectly.

Comment: Player for what platform?  What devices?  All the devices have different capability.

Comment: Hello Brad, in standard browsers for computers, I already have app for android and iOS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Muses radio player supports mp3, acc+ and ogg streams http://www.musesradioplayer.com/setup. You can create your own skins if you install it on your own server.

Comment: Very good indeed. But have to put a file called crossdomain.xml I do not know where, I use shoutcast, you have any idea where to put this file?

thank you very much